# How to inform date-fns about the input date format?

Tags: date-format

I need to return all of my input dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. Some input dates are in German format (dd/MM/yyyy) while others are in US format (MM/dd/yyyy).

I expect/want the code below to return "1979-12-31" in both cases. Instead, the second console output reads "1979-31-12" which means [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/docs/format) didn't notice the input date was in German format. How can I tell it that it's in German format, other than by passing the German locale to it as below?

```
const dateUS = '12/31/1979';
console.log('result with dinput date in US format: ', 
  format(new Date(dateUS), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
);

import { deLocale } from 'date-fns/locale/de';

const dateDE = '31/12/1979';
console.log('result with input date in DE format: ', 
  format(new Date(dateDE), 'yyyy-MM-dd', {
    locale: deLocale
  })
);
```

Comment: you cannot unless you know what format dates are in for example like 10/12/1999 you cannot decide without locale

Comment: I mostly try to use unix time easier to translate to other formats

Comment: Not sure I understand, what do you mean by "cannot decide without locale"? (I did include the locale in my code yet it does not work). Could you provide a code example based on my snippet that makes use of the UNIX time you mentioned please?